# Replace “&lt;” and “&gt;” with “<” and “>” in SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

I am new to XML in SQL Server.

I have a query like this

```
declare @EstimateType char(1)

select top 1
    ISNULL((case when @EstimateType='x' or @EstimateType='C' then
SUBSTRING((select ',' + ItemTitle from tb_Pricecatalogue WHERE PricecatalogueID IN(select PricecatalogueID from tb_DeliveryItem WHERE PriceCatalogueID = 0 )
FOR XML PATH('')),2,8000) 
WHEN ISNULL((select top 1 et.ItemID FROM tb_DeliveryItem et WHERE et.DeliveryItemID = 252602 AND isdeleted = 0 ),0)>0 THEN
 SUBSTRING((select ',' + ItemTitlevalue from tb_EstItemDescription WHERE EstimateItemID=
 (246666)  FOR XML PATH('')),2,8000) END),'') as ItemTitle    

from tb_DeliveryItem d  
where DeliveryItemID=252602 AND IsDeleted=0
```

it return the xml as

```
A4 PUR Bound Booklet - 4pp Cover + 116pp Text&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;&lt;br/&gt;
```

How can I replace the `&gt;` with `>` and `&lt;` with `<`?

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this can be achieved using the [TYPE Directive](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/type-directive-in-for-xml-queries)

I've modified the query to add the usage of `TYPE` directive alongside `FOR XML PATH('')`

```
DECLARE @EstimateType char(1)

SELECT TOP 1
ISNULL((
CASE WHEN @EstimateType='x' OR @EstimateType='C' THEN
    SUBSTRING(( SELECT ',' + ItemTitle FROM tb_Pricecatalogue 
                WHERE PricecatalogueID IN ( SELECT PricecatalogueID 
                                            FROM tb_DeliveryItem 
                                            WHERE PriceCatalogueID = 0 )
                FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),2,8000)
    WHEN ISNULL((SELECT TOP 1 et.ItemID 
                FROM tb_DeliveryItem et 
                WHERE et.DeliveryItemID = 252602 
                AND isdeleted = 0 ),0)>0 THEN
    SUBSTRING(( SELECT ',' + ItemTitlevalue 
                FROM tb_EstItemDescription 
                WHERE EstimateItemID= (246666) FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE),2,8000) END),'') as ItemTitle    
FROM tb_DeliveryItem d  
WHERE DeliveryItemID=252602 AND IsDeleted=0
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Can you accept this as an answer if it has helped you solve your problem/